# Get Values from Adapter to main activity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, android-database

I was trying to get the values which i have entered in edit text using recycler view. On click of submit i want to save the text given in the editetxt to the table.

1. using Json stored the data to the table - Success
2. upto array adapter i got the data
3. now how to move the data from adapter to the main activity to save the data into table on single submit button. [enter image description here][1]

   Activity

   ```
    public class fertlizerRequest extends AppCompatActivity  {

    Button submit_btn,view_btn;
    RecyclerView material_lv;
    ArrayList<ProductData> arrayList;
    ProductsAdapter myAdapterP;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    DBHelperClass dbHelperClass = new DBHelperClass(this);
    Integer[] enteredNumber = new Integer[1000];




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fertlizer_request);

        datacasting();

        view_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                PlantLocationAssy plantLocationAssy = new PlantLocationAssy();
                plantLocationAssy.execute();

            }
        });

        submit_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(fertlizerRequest.this, "Edited Item are ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }


    void datacasting(){

        material_lv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.materialreq_lv);
        submit_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sbt_btn);
        view_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.vie_btn);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        material_lv.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    }

    void fetchProductData(){

        arrayList = dbHelperClass.getProductsDataFromDB();
        myAdapterP = new ProductsAdapter(fertlizerRequest.this, arrayList, new ProductsAdapter.onEditTextChanged() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(int position, String charSeq) {
                enteredNumber[position] = Integer.valueOf(charSeq);
                System.out.println("==================================== " + position);
                Toast.makeText(fertlizerRequest.this, "Entered value is " + myAdapterP.getItemId(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        material_lv.setAdapter(myAdapterP);
        myAdapterP.notifyDataSetChanged();
        System.out.println("==================================== " + myAdapterP.getItemCount() );
    }



    private class PlantLocationAssy extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            fetchProductData();

        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }
    }
   ```

   }

Adapter

```
    package com.example.fertlizertrackerapp.Adapter;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.fertlizertrackerapp.Model.ProductData;
import com.example.fertlizertrackerapp.R;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ProductsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductsAdapter.Holder> {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<ProductData> arrayList;
    private onEditTextChanged onEditTextChanged;


    public ProductsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ProductData> arrayList, onEditTextChanged onEditTextChanged) {
        this.context = context;
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
        this.onEditTextChanged = onEditTextChanged;
    }




    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Holder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.cust_lv_fertilizer_request, parent, false);
        return new Holder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final Holder holder, final int position) {


        final ProductData productData = arrayList.get(position);

        // get for view
        String productId = productData.getProductId();
        final String material = productData.getMaterial();
        String materialCode = productData.getMaterialCode();

        //set view
        holder.productId.setText(productId);
        holder.material.setText(material);
        holder.materialCode.setText(materialCode);

        holder.quantity.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                onEditTextChanged.onTextChanged(position,s.toString());

                String qty = holder.quantity.getText().toString();

                Toast.makeText(context, "Value Changed is " + material + " : " + qty, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView productId, material,materialCode;
        EditText quantity;

        public Holder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            productId = itemView.findViewById(R.id.productId_tv);
            material = itemView.findViewById(R.id.materialName_tv);
            materialCode = itemView.findViewById(R.id.materialCode_tv);
            quantity = (itemView).findViewById(R.id.materialQuantity_edt);
        }


    }


    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return super.getItemViewType(position);
    }

    public interface onEditTextChanged{
        void onTextChanged(int position, String charSeq);

    }



}


Model

package com.example.fertlizertrackerapp.Model;

public class ProductData {

    String ProductId, Material,MaterialCode;
    int quantity = 0;

    public ProductData(String productId,  String material,String materialCode) {
        this.ProductId = productId;
        this.Material = material;
        this.MaterialCode = materialCode;
    }

    public String getProductId() {
        return ProductId;
    }

    public void setProductId(String productId) {
        ProductId = productId;
    }

    public String getMaterial() {
        return Material;
    }

    public void setMaterial(String material) {
        Material = material;
    }

    public String getMaterialCode() {
        return MaterialCode;
    }

    public void setMaterialCode(String materialCode) {
        MaterialCode = materialCode;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
}


DBHelperClass

    package com.example.fertlizertrackerapp;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import com.example.fertlizertrackerapp.Model.PlantData;
import com.example.fertlizertrackerapp.Model.ProductData;
import com.example.fertlizertrackerapp.Model.ProductRateData;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DBHelperClass extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final int DBVersion = 1;
    public static final String DB_Godown = "FertlizerApp.db";



    public static final String DB_ProductListTABLE = "ProductDetails";
    public static final String DB_ProductId = "ProductId";
    public static final String DB_productStatus = "productStatus";
    public static final String DB_Material = "Material";
    public static final String DB_MaterialCode = "MaterialCode";
    public static final String DB_MaterialStatus = "Status";
    public static final String DB_MaterialCreatedBy = "CreatedBy";
    public static final String DB_MaterialCreatedOn = "CreatedOn";
    public static final String DB_MaterialUpdatedBy = "UpdatedBy";
    public static final String DB_MaterialUpdatedOn = "UpdatedOn";




    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL(" CREATE TABLE " + DB_ProductListTABLE + "(" + DB_ProductId + " TEXT, "
            + DB_productStatus + " TEXT, "
            + DB_Material + " TEXT, "
            + DB_MaterialCode + " TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, "
            + DB_MaterialStatus + " TEXT, "
            + DB_MaterialCreatedBy + " TEXT, "
            + DB_MaterialCreatedOn + " TEXT, "
            + DB_MaterialUpdatedBy + " TEXT, "
            + DB_MaterialUpdatedOn + " TEXT)");

        }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

       
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DB_ProductListTABLE);
        

    }


    public Boolean insertProductDetails(String v_ProductId, String v_productStatus, String v_Material, String v_MaterialCode, String v_MaterialStatus, String v_MaterialCreatedBy, String v_MaterialCreatedOn, String v_MaterialUpdatedBy, String v_MaterialUpdatedOn) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValue = new ContentValues();
        contentValue.put("ProductId", v_ProductId);
        contentValue.put("productStatus", v_productStatus);
        contentValue.put("Material", v_Material);
        contentValue.put("MaterialCode", v_MaterialCode);
        contentValue.put("Status", v_MaterialStatus);
        contentValue.put("CreatedBy", v_MaterialCreatedBy);
        contentValue.put("CreatedOn", v_MaterialCreatedOn);
        contentValue.put("UpdatedBy", v_MaterialUpdatedBy);
        contentValue.put("UpdatedOn", v_MaterialUpdatedOn);

        long result = db.insert(DB_ProductListTABLE, null, contentValue);

        if (result == -1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }


    public DBHelperClass(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_Godown, null, DBVersion);

    }


   public ArrayList<ProductData> getProductsDataFromDB(){


        ArrayList<ProductData> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " + DB_ProductListTABLE, null);

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

            String productId = cursor.getString(0);
            String material = cursor.getString(2);
            String materialCode = cursor.getString(3);

            ProductData productData = new ProductData(productId,material,materialCode);

            arrayList.add(productData);

            System.out.println("00000000000000000000 Product 00000000000000000000000000000  " + material);

        }
        return arrayList;

    }


}


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikNRR.jpg
```

Comment: Please have a look at [this] answer. [this]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63518358/how-to-get-data-from-a-dialog-recyclerview-to-its-hosted-activity/63521803#63521803

Comment: Helped me allot.